# Integrals of orthogonal functions

Tags: real-analysis, orthogonality

Suppose we have an orthogonal basis $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ for $L^2[0,1]$. Do the functions
\begin{align*}
u_k(t) := \int_t^1e_k(s)\text{d} s,\quad k \in \mathbb{N},
\end{align*}
also satisfy
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1u_i(s)u_j(s)\text{d} s = 0, \quad i \neq j?
\end{align*}
This is true for the the functions $\{\sqrt{2}\sin{(k - 1/2)\pi t}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ for example, and also seems to be true for the shifted Legendre polynomials. If it's not generally true, I'm curious under what conditions it might be true.

Answer (score 3):

Let $e_k(s) = e^{2 \pi i k s}$. Then the formula above gives
$u_0(t)=1-t$, $u_1(t) = {1 \over 2 \pi i} (1-e^{2 \pi i s})$,
and $\int_0^1 u_0(s) u_1(s) ds = -{1+i\pi \over 4 \pi^2}$.